# Refresh only one div after AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got a div in which my shopping cart is shown. So i do an ajax request in which something is added to shopping cart. After i want to reload the div of the shopping cart to update it, it is not working for me.

This is where i call the JQuery:

```html
<a
  class="button_green"{if $module_data.PRODUCTS_NAME != ''}
  title="{$module_data.PRODUCTS_NAME|replace:'"':'&quot;'} {$txt.text_buy}"{/if}
  onclick="return checkAddToCart('{$module_data.QTY_DATA.ID}', '{$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}', '{$smarty.session.customer_id}', '{$smarty.session.customers_id.customers_status_id}')"
>
  <span class="button-outer">
    <span class="button-inner">{$button.add_to_cart}</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
function checkAddToCart(tid, pid, cid, csid) {
  tid = Number(tid);
  var bought = Number($("#gm_attr_calc_qty_"+pid).val());
  pid = Number(pid);
  cid = Number(cid);
  csid = Number(csid);

  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "check_basket.php",
    data: {
      bought: bought,
      pid: pid,
      cid: cid,
      csid: csid
    },
    success: function(data){  
      $("#dropdown_shopping_cart_inner").load("shopping_cart.php");
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

As a result i am getting passed on to this site, it just shows me this little icon, console says no error:

[image: icon]

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: How are you calling that function? Show more code

Comment: Well it does not refresh, instead i am passes me on a site which just shows a little gif jumping around, i will  add a screenshot

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski Do you find any errors on the console?

Comment: @PraveenKumar nope, console says nothign about errors

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski Check in your Net tab, if there are requests going for `check_basket.php` and `shopping_cart.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
success: function(data){  
    $("#dropdown_shopping_cart_inner").html(data);
}
```

In `check_basket.php` file, echo the content what ever you want to add to a div.

what ever echoed in `check_basket.php`, will come in `data` of ajax success.

Comment: both are different `urls`.

Comment: yeah but why should i echo the HTML formatted content of my shopping cart if it is already there and i just have to update it?